quarkus.config.locations behavior changed in Quarkus 3.10.0 vs Quarkus 2.16?
I am currently upgrading a project from Quarkus 2.16.10-FINAL to the latest release (3.10.0 at the time of writing).
In our app we were using configuration files defined using the "quarkus.config.locations" and it worked fine.
Basically we had something like this in our application.properties
%dev.quarkus.config.locations = application-dev.properties
%test.quarkus.config.locations = application-test.properties
%prod.quarkus.config.locations = file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-config.properties,file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-sensitive-config.properties

"%prod.quarkus.config.locations" corresponding to k8s volume mounts in our app container.
This worked really well on Quarkus 2.16
Since moving to 3.10.0 it seems that Quarkus is not finding the files:
Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.10.0:build (default) on project <OUR_PROJECT>: Failed to build quarkus application: SRCFG00035: Failed to load resource
I was assuming that some change had been made and that the entries under %prod.quarkus.config.locations were being resolved a build time.
So I tried instead adding this parameter as a java runtime parameter in the Dockerfile. Something like:
ENTRYPOINT ["java -Dquarkus.config.locations=file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-config.properties,file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-sensitive-config.properties"]
Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work any better.
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "java -Dquarkus.config.locations=file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-config.properties,file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-sensitive-config.properties": stat java -Dquarkus.config.locations=file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-config.properties,file:///opt/<OUR_DIR>/quarkus_install/config/application-sensitive-config.properties: no such file or directory: unknown
Why is this not working as it did? Is there an alternative to achieve what we want (we need to have config files that are generated with approriate values at install time by our Helm charts).
Thanks

its a big version jump.  I suggest you identify the exact version that causes the crash after 2.16 and then see the information of the release under  https://quarkus.io/blog/tag/release/

hmmmm not sure that I can face doing all the upgrades between 2.16.10 and 3.10 ... especially that this involved a change of jdk in between.

Hi JCompetence, thanks for your reply.
I have finally worked around this by using the QUARKUS_CONFIG_LOCATIONS environment variable instead of the quarkus.config.locations parameter.
After testing, it seems that the value of the quarkus.config.locations parameter is indeed resolved at build time which makes it useless for my purpose.
Setting the QUARKUS_CONFIG_LOCATIONS env variable with the mounted file paths in the k8s container worked fine finally.
